# FFmpeg throws a duration, timestamp, pts error

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg

I've been using an ffmpeg command called from a python script to transcode folders of files:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in_file.mov -loglevel warning -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 10000k -minrate 8000k -maxrate 10000k -bufsize 4800k -threads 0 -movflags +faststart -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac out_file.mov
```

This has been working fine, but on some newer Macs i've started getting the following error:

```
[mov @ 0x7fa92e010c00] Application provided duration: -9223372036854775808 / timestamp: -9223372036854775808 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mov @ 0x7fa92e010c00] pts has no value
```

This doesn't appear to have any effect on the file, but I would like to know what's causing it and if it may cause errors later on.

System specs for no errors:

- IMac Pro, MacOS 10.15.7, Python 3.7.9, FFmpeg 4.3.2

System specs with erroes

- MacBook Pro 2019 15", MacOS 10.15.7, Python 3.7.0, FFmpeg 4.4

I'm assuming my problem is caused by the newer version of FFmpeg, but I'm still unsure of what's causing it.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9328  &  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9402

Comment: @RichardBarber so is this a known bug in 4.4?

Comment: It could be because your error indicates the presence of a timecode track.  These errors were reported against 4.4 but actually need to be checked against a build from the git master head which is already significantly ahead of the release.

Comment: I've compiled a version from git and it produces exactly the same warnings.

Comment: In that case, I would urge you to file amendments on both existing tickets.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this behaviour started with version 4.4 (which I've built myself locally yesterday from sources). The previous versions were 4.2.* and 4.3.* and they didn't throw these diagnostics. So I assume the question should be addressed to the ffmpeg development team, something has changed recently.

Comment: I actually started a ticket on the ffmpeg bug tracker, and was told "yes we can reproduce this" with no information given on why it was happening, or if it was a bug or feature. They didn't seem very interested. See the ticket: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9328